# Обновлять время

Tags: java, android

Вывожу время в `TextView` через `SimpleDateFormat`. А как обновлять время в приложении? В статус баре если например уже 18:02, то в приложении у меня так и висит 18:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать кастомную вьюшку наследующую TextView

```
public class TextClockView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{

private SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat;

public TextClockView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public TextClockView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TextClockView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Date date=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            setText(mDateFormat.format(date));
            getHandler().postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
}
```

Или поискать уже готовый виджет в сдк, к примеру ***android.widget.Chronometer***

Comment: Получилось. А как применить свой шрифт к такому textview? К обычному я знаю Как, но к кастомному запутался.

Comment: просто в init вызвать setTypeface

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй метод invalidate() для обновления view